# blueimp-gallery calling loading.gif causing error

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, blueimp

I've recently taken over a project using the blueimp-image-gallery. Everything seemed to be working fine until I started working on some tests.

When the image is clicked, before the lightbox is rendered, there is a call to `/img/loading.gif` that's causing a 404 exception.  When running rspec, it fails when it hits this 404 error.

There are no issues with viewing the images, and everything appears to be fine otherwise.

My question, is there a place in the source code or otherwise (jquery?) to disable to call to the loading.gif?  If not, can I change the path for the loading image it's looking for?

I looked through the source code, but didn't see something that looked it like would be easy to modify and wanted to check here first.

Let me know if there's any extra info you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this is a late answer, but for anyone else with the same issue:

The loading image, error image and other images are defined in the CSS file and not in the js files. The following is the snippet where I found the loading.gif being used:

```
.blueimp-gallery > .slides > .slide-loading {
   background: url(../img/loading.gif) center no-repeat;
   background-size: 64px 64px;
}
```

You can just override this in your site's css, to avoid future hassles when updating blueimp-gallery to a newer version.